RecyclerView LayoutManager functionality in LazyColumn or LazyRow?
How to get Recyclerview LayoutManager functionality in Jetpack compose?
LazyColumn{
    items(items.itemCount){

    }
}


See here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/migrate/migration-scenarios/recycler-view#migration-steps

LinearLayoutManager
LazyColumn or LazyRow

GridLayoutManager
LazyVerticalGrid or LazyHorizontalGrid

StaggeredGridLayoutManager
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid or LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid

you can set like this|
LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    items(data) {
        ListItem(it)
    }
}

